# iOS Swift - Multiple activity indicator (spinners) appear in webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm working on a webView based screen and I want to have an activity indicator to spin while the web content is loading.

Since I have to use the same activity indicator in another screen of the app, I've put the code in static functions in a specific file.

The activity indicator seems to work fine for some web (simple) web pages but I have an issue when I load more complex pages. **The activity indicators gets duplicate several times.** *(See screenshot below)*

On the screenshot, the first activity indicator has the correct layout but the one below is darker which implies that several other activity indicators have been overlaid on top of each other. **And then they never disappears.**

When it comes to code:

I have a webView and two delegate methods controlling the activity indicators.

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        EBUtil.startActivityIndicator(self)
    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        EBUtil.stopActivityIndicator(self)

    }
}
```

I guess it comes from the fact that webViewDidStartLoad gets called several times. Any idea how I can prevent this behaviour to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Edouard

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code for my VC.

```
class NewsDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

//MARK: - @IBOUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

//MARK: - VARIABLES 

var url: String!

//MARK: - APP LIFE CYCLE

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if url != nil {

        let urlToLoad = NSURL(string: url)

        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: urlToLoad as! URL) as URLRequest)
    }
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        EBUtil.startActivityIndicator(self)
    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        EBUtil.stopActivityIndicator(self)

    }
}
```

}

And code for activity indicator start and stop:

```
 static func startActivityIndicator(_ sender: UIViewController) {


    print("START ANIMATING")

    if let view = sender.view {

        activityIndicatorBackground = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.center.x - 25, y: view.center.y - 25, width: 50, height: 50))
        activityIndicatorBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        activityIndicatorBackground.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT-1)
        activityIndicatorBackground.alpha = 0.6
        activityIndicatorBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        view.addSubview(activityIndicatorBackground)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
        activityIndicator.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
}

static func stopActivityIndicator(_ sender: UIViewController) {
    print("STOP ANIMATING")
    activityIndicatorBackground.removeFromSuperview()
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

Comment: share complete code of this view controller..

Comment: would you share how do you add your webView to your screen (i.e. root view)?

Comment: You are creating new indicator everytime you call that code i guess, try remove the current one if it called again with a Bool or simply use the same instance of it with singleton class, not class function

Comment: @tropicalfish, the webview is added via storyboard and connected with IBOutlet then set its delegate to self in my viewController (see edited answer for full code).

Comment: @Tj3n: will try. thanks.

Comment: Also show startActivityIndicator, stopActivityIndicator code.

Comment: @PremaJanoti: see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

add below line in your viewController class -

```
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
```

And update your `startActivityIndicator` `stopActivityIndicator` method like below-

```
  func startActivityIndicator(_ sender: UIViewController) {

    print("START ANIMATING")

    if let view = sender.view {
        if activityIndicator != nil {
           activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        activityIndicator?.center = view.center
        activityIndicator?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        activityIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        activityIndicator?.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator?.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
        activityIndicator?.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator!)
        activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
}


func stopActivityIndicator(_ sender: UIViewController) {
    print("STOP ANIMATING")
    activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
    activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

Hope it will work for you :)